# Why does the UICollectionView's delegate methods don't work?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I created a `collectionView` and I made it's delegate conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol attached to the main **ViewController** in order to modify some aspects of the `UICollectionView's` cells.
Initially I did this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.delegate = self 

}
```

then I realised that this didn't work since there was an error, so I fixed it doing this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.delegate = self as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

}
```

The problem is that every method I try to implement in the **ViewController** doesn't seem to work during runtime.

f.e. I implemented this method here:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/3, height: collectionView.frame.width/3)

}
```

but it doesn't work during the run of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "so I fixed it doing this"

You made the error go away, but you didn't fix it. You need to make your view controller class actually adopt `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` by either adding it to its class declaration like this:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

or by adding it to an extension of your view controller, like this:

```
extension ProfileViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```